# Some problems with trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Actually, this is the original question:

A particle moves along the x-axis so that the distance traveled in time $t$ is given by $x=2t + \cos 3t$. Find the distance between the first two positions of rest.

The ans given is 0.37 unit.

Comment: $2t+\cos\,3t=0$ is a transcendental equation; there isn't a general method to solve equations like these explicitly. One could use *numerical* methods for generating approximate solutions, though.

Comment: @J.M. I see, thanks a lot!

Comment: @J.M. We do not need to solve $x(t)=2t+\cos(3t)=0$ at all. We need to solve $v(t) = 0$, where $v(t)= x'(t)$ is the velocity. The roots are just arcsin of some number.

Comment: @Sri: I was addressing [revision 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/66358/1) of the question. Now I see OP edited to a different question. Not cool.

Comment: Not you, @Sri. You had no fault. It was the OP's bait-and-switch that had me bummed.

Comment: So @Sophia: Your initial translation of the problem was wrong. You need to solve $x'(t) = 0$ for the two smallest positive $t_1, t_2$ and then calculate the distance travelled between these two times, i.e. $x(t_2) - x(t_1)$.

Comment: @Sophia When you are editing a question, please do not edit it so substantially that it will invalidate a comment or answer. If such an edit is necessary, then **mention somewhere (either in the question itself or in the comments) that you have modified the question**.  Otherwise different people will be seeing/solving different revisions of the question, leading to unnecessary confusion.

Comment: I found the solution already, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a time scaling by means of $t:={\tau\over3}$. Then we have to study the function
$$x(\tau):={2\over 3}\tau+\cos\tau$$ with derivative
$$\dot x(\tau)={2\over3}-\sin\tau\ .$$
Beginning at $\tau=0$ the first time of rest is at $\tau_1=\arcsin{2\over3}$, and the second at $\tau_2=\pi-\arcsin{2\over3}$. In between $\dot x(\tau)$ is negative; therefore the distance $d$ traveled in the time interval $[\tau_1,\tau_2]$ is given by
$$\eqalign{d =x(\tau_1)-x(\tau_2)&={2\over3}\bigl(2\arcsin{2\over3}-\pi\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\arcsin{2\over3}\bigr)-\cos\bigl(\pi-\arcsin{2\over3}\bigr)\cr
&={4\over3}\arcsin{2\over3}-{2\pi\over3}+{2\over3}\sqrt{5}\cr &\doteq 0.369287\ \cr
}$$

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Srivatsan's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66358/some-problems-with-trigonometry#comment156733_66358), the points of rest, where $x'(t)=0$, can be found to be:
$$
2-3\sin(3t)=0 \; \; \to \; \; t=\cases{
&$\frac13 \left(2\pi n  +\sin^{-1}\left(\frac23\right)\right)$\\
&$\frac13 \left(2\pi n +\pi +\sin^{-1}\left(\frac23\right)\right)$
}
$$

Comment: What about $t=(1/3)(\pi-\arcsin(2/3))$? Oh, I think you may just have a plus sign where you need a minus in the second case.